# Programmatically Add column and attribute in catalog/product in magento

Tags: magento

I want to add a new column comment in catalog/product? how can i do that with this code ?

```
    /* @var $installer Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup */
$installer = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/setup','catalog_setup');

$installer->startSetup();

$installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
    $installer->getTable('catalog/product'),
    'my_column_name',
    array(
        'type'    => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,
        'length'  => 255,
        'comment' => 'My Column Name'
    )
);

$installer->addAttribute(
    'catalog_product',
    'my_column_name',
    array(
        'label' => 'Initial Label',
        'type'  => 'static'
    )
);

$installer->endSetup();
```

How can i add this code to my custom module to upgrade the install script of catalog/product ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies in your question only,
in your custom module, create a upgrade script if an sql setup script already exists or else create an sql setup script and write down the code

```
   /* @var $installer Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup */
$installer = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/setup','catalog_setup');

$installer->startSetup();

$installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
    $installer->getTable('catalog/product'),
    'my_column_name',
    array(
        'type'    => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,
        'length'  => 255,
        'comment' => 'My Column Name'
    )
);

$installer->addAttribute(
    'catalog_product',
    'my_column_name',
    array(
        'label' => 'Initial Label',
        'type'  => 'static'
    )
);

$installer->endSetup();
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually i figured it out. in my [namespace]_[module]_model_resource_setup..

just added a list of array for the new attribute of products

```
'catalog_product' => array(
            'entity_model' => 'catalog/product',
            'attribute_model' => 'catalog/resource_eav_attribute',
            'table' => 'catalog/product',
            'attributes' => array(
                'mycustomproductcode' => array(
                    'group' => 'AddedProductattrib/Tab',
                    'lable' => 'mycustomattrib',
                    'type' => 'varchar',
                    'input' => 'text',
                    'default' => '0',
                    'class' => '',
                    'backend' => '',
                    'frontend' => '',
                    'source' => '',
                    'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
                    'visible' => true,
                    'required' => false,
                    'user_defined' => false,
                    'searchable' => false,
                    'filterable' => false,
                    'comparable' => false,
                    'visible_on_front' => false,
                    'visible_in_advance_search' => false,
                    'unique' => false
                )
            )
        ),
//add more entity attributes
```